# Size Assertion in Jemeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I need to know what is the average value to put in as size assertion in jmeter to test the APIs performance.

currently I am getting 6425 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If the API returns the same response and the size of the response is the same - then put `6425` there like:

[image]

If you need to compare response **content**, not only the size the best option would be going for [MD5Hex Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MD5Hex_Assertion), in that case you will need to tick `Save response as MD5 Hash` box under "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler:

[image]

the idea is that identical respones have identical [MD5 checksums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), any difference will cause the assertion failure.

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://admin.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)